# How do you show spinner if RxJava observable takes to long?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I feel like someone has to have tried this, but I can't figure out a nice way to do something if an observable takes to long.

This is the flow I want.

```
Start a search.
If the search takes longer than some time,
    show a spinner or show progress bar.
When finished do subscription action and hide spinner/progress bar.
```

The closest I can think of is like a Zip

```
manager.search(searchTerm)
       .zip(Observable.Timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
       .subscribe(
           // if the search is non null then we are good
           // if the long time is non 0 we need to show spinner
       );
```

Is there something better to do? I have been trying all day with no success. In a perfect world I feel like I would want something like

```
manager.search(searchTerm)
       .timeout(i -> /* do timeout stuff */, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .subscribe(item -> /* do search result stuff */);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by publishing the search Observable through the timeout:

```
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.just(1).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

source
.doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("Starting"))
.publish(o -> 
    o.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.<Integer>fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Spinning...");
        return null;
    })).ignoreElements().mergeWith(o)
)
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(v -> {
    System.out.println("Hide spinner if shown.");
    System.out.println(v);
});
```

This works by splitting the source into two hot lanes: the first lane will run a `timeout` operator which when times out, starts another Observable with the side-effect that shows the spinning control. One of the ways is to use `fromCallable` for this and ignore its result (this also avoid duplication). The second lane will be unchanged and merged with the timeout lane to deliver the actual value.

Comment: From `BlockingObservable` documentation: "But is generally inappropriate for production applications (if you think you need to use a BlockingObservable this is usually a sign that you should rethink your design)." So when is using blocking observable appropriate and when not?

Comment: I would say that it's ok to use BlockingObservable in some cases, when it really improves the readability of your code.

Comment: I used `BlockingObservable` here for demonstration purposes so the app doesn't quit before seeing all the printlines. In production, you just don't call `toBlocking` and that's it.

Comment: @akarnokd Could you please comment on why we don't need to call `connect()` after `publish()` operator to make this observable start emitting items? Is it not converted to a `ConnectableObservable` by applying `publish()`?

Comment: The publish(Func1) returns an Observable and automatically connects to the source, which is only shared for the duration of the Func1 call. This means that two subscribers will trigger two subscription to the source of publish(Func1).

Comment: This did work, but I did change a little bit because I couldn't find a Observable.fromCallable() that returned a Observer for RxJava. Instead I did a doOnError + onErrorReturn. It wasn't as elegant but got the job done.

Comment: `fromCallable` is available since 1.0.15.

Comment: @akarnokd OH I didn't realize I was behind in version. Is there a way to run a Observable.fromCallback(...) with a scheduler? I have to do UI work so I need it to run on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(). I am sure there is I am just new and still shaky on schedulers.

Comment: Apply `subscribeOn` just after `fromCallback`.

Comment: @akarnokd /facepalm I need to know how subscribeOn and observeOn work better. I should have known that lol.

Answer (score 1):

Today i found a bit odd but working solution. Idea is to use interval instead of timer.

```
    fun <T> base_delayed_progress_observable(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T>
    {
        val timer = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //Creates observable that will emit Long++ each 100 miliseconds
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(
                    {
                        if (it == 10L)//Here we check current timer value. For example here i check if it is 1 second gone (100 miliseconds * 10 = 1 second)
                        {
                            //here we put all we need to show progress/spinner an so on
                        }
                    })

        return Observable.zip(source, timer,
            BiFunction<T, Long, T> { t1, t2 ->
                //Here we return our original Obervable zipped with timer
                //Timer will be cancelled when our source Observable gets to OnComplete
                return@BiFunction t1
            }).doFinally(
            {
                //Here we can dismiss all progress dilogs/spinner
            })
    }
```